# Mesos unsets some environment variables

Tags: shell, environment-variables, mesos

My mesos jobs run without the `LANG` environment variable set. I have verified that the slaves have the variable set, so the mesos job must be unsetting the variable, but I cannot figure out where this is done.

I can explicitly set the environment variable for each job, but I would like this to be set globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the agent flag `--executor_environment_variables`.

From the agent command line help:

> JSON object representing the environment variables that should be
>   passed to the executor, and thus subsequently task(s). By default this
>   flag is none.
>
> Users have to define executor environment explicitly.

Example:

`mesos-slave --executor_environment_variables='{ "LANG": "C" }' [...]`